# Preloading using includes on unrelated models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Suppose I have three models, set up something like this:

```ruby
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end
```

I want to query all tests whose student does not have car. Preloaded.

I've tried the following:

`Test.includes(:cars) # does not work because the two are not associated`
`Test.joins('inner join cars ON tests.student_id = cars.student_id') # works, but it doesn't preload the Cars model in my result`

I'd prefer not to create a `has_many :through` relationship, because they really aren't related at all, but I'm not opposed to it if that's the best solution.

Thoughts?

Rails 4.1.5
PostgreSQL 9.3.4
ruby 2.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A join across three tables is an inefficient way to do this.  Rails might even be smart enough to realise this and split it into seperate db queries.

I would do it like this, which has two simple queries instead

```
student_ids_with_car = Car.select("student_id").distinct
@tests = Test.where("student_id not in (?)", student_ids_with_car)
```

Comment: Oh, I like this. Why is the join inefficient though? I thought the whole purpose of using `includes` is to reduce the number of queries, hence being more efficient?

Comment: Joins are SLOW.  When you have very large tables they get exponentially slower and use a lot more memory.  2 (or three, or more) fast non-join queries might be more efficient in a lot of cases, and their execution time grows linearly, rather than exponentially, as table size increases.

Comment: This is actually a nice lesson in pragmatism - it's always best to weigh up alternatives rather than just do what the textbook says.  Especially since the textbook is probably telling you what you can do rather than what you should do.

Comment: @MaxWilliams you could do `Test.where.not(student_id: student_ids_with_car)` which is much simpler

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ seems to suggest that there is not much difference between joins and not in (although compared to the link your solution returns the intermediate query into ruby land - could get expensive with large numbers of distinct student_ids (e.g. 10s of thousands)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `has_many :through` to associations and associations of those associations at the same time.

```
Test.includes(:student => :cars)
```

Will include student's and their cars (by default it will preload, you can force a joins based include by using `eager_load` instead of `preload`).

Comment: While this exactly answers what I asked in my question, I marked Max's as the accepted because it answered the question I didn't know I should have been asking. Thanks though!